# ureadahead appears to be caching files from Trash Can

Tags: delete, trash, ureadahead

With one of the fastest NVMe SSD's on the market I'm not even sure `ureadahead` has been beneficial to me. After reading these messages though I'm wondering if it is detrimental:

```
Oct 16 16:48:57 alien ureadahead[313]: ureadahead:/home/rick/.local/share/Trash/info/eyesome-cfg.bak.trashinfo: No such file or directory
Oct 16 16:48:57 alien ureadahead[313]: ureadahead:/home/rick/.local/share/Trash/info/eyesome-cfg.sh.trashinfo: No such file or directory
Oct 16 16:48:57 alien ureadahead[313]: ureadahead:/home/rick/.local/share/Trash/info/monitor-eyesome.sh.trashinfo: No such file or directory
```

Yesterday before installing Android Studio I wanted to trim down on storage space so I emptied the trash. Upon rebooting just now `ureadahead` is complaining it can't find files in the trash anymore.

I can see the value of `ureadahead` caching often used programs into RAM by why would it be caching the trash can into RAM? Especially if trash is write many times and then read & delete once in blue moon.

Perhaps someone familiar with `ureadahead` can explain the rationale?

Comment: It's probably caching recently-used files and some happen to be in the trash can. I assume it doesn't care where the files are (other than perhaps on `tmpfs` or something). I don't think it caches files in the trash can that haven't been used recently. As far as benefit, the files have to be read into RAM when a program reads them, even for SSDs, so this will save that effort if the file is already in RAM. While SSDs might have decent throughput, they are still much slower than RAM in terms of latency.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex the three files in question were sent to trash weeks if not a month ago. This leaves me to believe it is caching everything it has ever encountered and not using a LRU (Least Recently Used) algorithm to flush out it's cache. Granted I do have 8 GB of RAM and `ureadahead` may be deciding "hey let's use all this juicy real estate". I'd rather the surplus was used by Kernel for caches and buffers though. Unless `ureadahead` is within that pool? I agree RAM is faster than Gen 3.0 x 4 PCIe NVM.e SSD (Samsung Pro 960) but I hope it's not being wasted when it can be put to better use.